# Hide elements vs DataTriggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

So I've just joined a windows phone team where they tend to do something along the lines of this:

```
<Image Width="74"
       Height="74"
       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ImageCatagory/shoot icon.png"
       Visibility="{Binding SomeBoolParameter,
       Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<Image Width="74"
       Height="74"
       Source="ms-appx:///Assets/ImageCatagory/shoot icon disabled.png"
       Visibility="{Binding SomeBoolParameter,
       Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

I've looked it over and thought to myself: Code duplication, loading 2 elements to the UI which (though minor) loads unnecessary memory - why load both images when you need only one at any given time?

I've changed it to look like this:

```
<Image x:Name="HelperButtonIcon"
       Margin="19 0">

       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>

             <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SomeBoolParameter}"
                                       ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                                       Value="True">

                   <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source"
                                              TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=HelperButtonIcon}"
                                              Value="ms-appx:///Assets/ImageCatagory/helper icon on.png" />

             </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
             <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding SomeBoolParameter}"
                                       ComparisonCondition="Equal"
                                       Value="False">

                   <core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source"
                                              TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=HelperButtonIcon}"
                                              Value="ms-appx:///Assets/ImageCatagory/helper icon off.png" />

             </core:DataTriggerBehavior>

</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

By using DataTriggers I only use 1 element at any given time, which seems more efficient to me.
However, the code gets a inflated a bit for quite a small matter, And in addition, I fear a bit for performance issues regarding the loading and switching of the images.
I haven't found anything regarding best practices on the matter, and even though I'm quite sure it's better, I'd like to be certain.
So the question is:

Is the usage of data triggers for switching the properties of these identical elements better than the visibility switch?

Comment: Note that you can also set the default value to one of those url in a style and make only one datatrigger for the second

Answer (score 0):

I would use neither option, and instead have this login in the view-model:

```
public bool SomeBoolParameter
{
    get { /* ... */ }
    set
    {
        //...
        OnPropertyChanged("SomeBoolParameter");
        OnPropertyChanged("ImageUrl");
    }
}

public string ImageUrl
{
    get
    {
        return SomeBoolParameter ? "..." : "...";
    }
}
```

```
<Image Source="{Binging ImageUrl}" />
```

Also, why not use the built-in `DataTriggers` if you don't do anything fancy? Would prefer the `DataTrigger` option if i had to choose between your two options, it is logically cleaner. I don't think that you should worry too much about memory unless it actually becomes an issue.

Comment: The issue I find with your suggestion is that it gives the ViewModel control over the UI. The VM supposedly "doesn't know/care" he's being presented so holding an image's URL counters one of the principle of the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @MichaelThePotato: The view model is a model for the view; it's supposed to describe the view data, so it holding data like image URLs is perfectly fine.

Comment: Not quite. The image URL has to do with the display, and nothing to do with the data. The UI itself should determine which image to display at any given time using the current state of the VM. it's not the VM's job to handle such things.
Therefore it's not proper for the VM to hold things like image URLs for the UI to display.

Comment: And regarding the original comment. DataTriggers aren't implemented in windows phone. So the Behavior-based implementation is the only available one.

Comment: The URL does not have to do anything with the data, your opinion what should go into the VM and what should not seems rather unsubstantiated to me.

Comment: Or rather URLs *are* data, unlike controls, which really do not belong in the VM.

Comment: I don't consider the image's URL as data because they are consistent to the screen (not specific towards certain displayed data or not).
They are have nothing to do with data that's queried from the server for instance.
They're not data that's flowing through the application like a user's profile picture for instance, or a photograph they've taken.
They are assets of the application.
Had the images been, for example, a user's profile pic, then naturally the VM will hold their current path and pass it along to the UI.
That's why I see a difference

Comment: I am aware of that distinction, but i don't think you are doing yourself any favour here, and i don't think MVVM makes any claims about whether the view model data has to be user related or dynamic in any way.

Comment: Adding something like an image URL for display creates a coupling, as small as it may be, between the UI and the VM.
Should I wish to keep the logic and make another UI, or greatly change the style in which I want to display my data, I'll have to change the VM since I'll be changing the manner in which my data is displayed.
Anything regarding the manner in which my data is displayed should be handled in XAML, and if code must be written then it should be written in converters or behaviors.
The VM's job is to reflect the state the application is in. The UI should decide what to do with it

Comment: @MichaelThePotato My opinion would be that it depends on scenario. If the image is not related to business logic, then I would agree that the URL should not appear in ViewModel. This is because it is the View designer's duty to find the appropriate images and tell the View where to find the image he/she designed (or he/she has gotten from other sources). If the URL is with the ViewModel, then everytime the designer changes the collection of images, he would need to tell the ViewModel programmer to make the change too - this does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

This topic will be quite controversial. Personally, I think that the original implementation is better. My reason for this as follows:

1. Modern RAMs are quite capable of storing millions of thumbnails.
2. If you constantly change the `SomeBoolProperty` value, you are going to do many times of reading operation from the hard disk. Disk IO are relatively slower. Also the images are going to be in your RAM every time your `Image`'s source changes, and the garbage collector would need to work harder.
3. You are making it a little harder for someone else to understand your code when someone else takes over your project in the future.

Of course, if the scenario is having 1000 images preloaded, waiting for a converter to tell them which one of the 1000 should be visible, then your solution is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: WPF does some image caching, actually.

Comment: @H.B. But if the caching is saved onto the hard disk, it is still as good as reading from original source. If it's on the RAM, then it's as good as the original solution.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to re-write the part in the first place was due to the fact that it was one of many cases in the project of code duplication.
Obviously code duplication is a really bad thing, it doubles the work during maintenance, and during development (the app isn't live yet).

So this was just a small case where I could get rid of such a bad thing.

Comment: @MichaelThePotato Then another way is to subclass `Image`, then adds dependency properties as appropriate to do this behavior. This way you are saving a lot more code duplication. And it would be very clear to whoever that would to maintain this what this whole idea is about.